# SQL Server Stored Procedure suddenly taking exponentially longer to run - where do I look to diagnose?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise: I have a stored procedure that has been running every 24 hours for over 2 years, and it has *always* taken anywhere between 30 and 45 minutes to execute. Today, for the first time in 2 years, it's still running after 3 hours. There is nothing different happening today than any other day (well obviously there IS, just not that I am aware of!)

I have no experience with looking into logs/history/etc in SQL Server, but I need to know where to start to diagnose this issue. This is our core stored procedure for our database so it's important that I find out what the issue is with haste.

Can someone direct me to a system table or query I could use to look into to see what's going on?

I did look at these two suggested threads:

[SQL Server - stored procedure suddenly become slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462312/sql-server-stored-procedure-suddenly-become-slow)

[Stored procedure taking 4 hours to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540313/stored-procedure-taking-4-hours-to-run)

but neither really had my answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search "trouble shooting long running queries". E.g., Find them via  [sp_blitzcache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/long-running-queries/) and investigate via [checklist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177500%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Your org can afford Enterprise, does it have a trained dba?

Comment: Also - check for blocking (unlikely but if no one is really in charge such things are increasingly possible).

Comment: @Smor the Enterprise license is free to us as a startup, less than one year old.  So no, we can't afford a dba.